# apparmor not working ubuntu 11.04 insize OpenVZ

Tags: ubuntu, openvz, apparmor

so it seems I have everything installed, but apparmor_status gives "apparmor module is not loaded." Also some apparmor scripts check for presence of /sys/module/apparmor and it is not there... Any idea of what is wrong?

Oh and it's virtual server using OpenVZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like OpenVZ and apparmor can't coexist

Answer (score 1):

To be more accurate; AppArmor (and SELinux) **does not work** with OpenVZ: they are incompatible.

AppArmor is designed to protect processes according to security policies within the Kernel. With OpenVZ, processes work within their own Container, separated from the Kernel. Protected by their own Init.

The way they access resources would not work with Apparmor, nor SELinux by design.