# How do I patch my kernel 3.2 with apparmor kernel patches?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apparmor

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with kernel 3.2 (64 bits)

I downloaded apparmor-2.8.0.tar.gz at https://launchpad.net/apparmor/2.8/2...r-2.8.0.tar.gz

After I untar, I go into apparmor-2.8.0/kernel-patches/3.2/ and there are 3 files:

```
0001-AppArmor-compatibility-patch-for-v5-network-controll.patch 
0002-AppArmor-compatibility-patch-for-v5-interface.patch
0003-AppArmor-Allow-dfa-backward-compatibility-with-broke.patch
```

I tried: 
`patch -p1 < 0001-AppArmor-compatibility-patch-for-v5-network-controll.patch`

```
can't find file to patch at input line 26
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|From 125fccb600288968aa3395883c0a394c47176fcd Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
|From: John Johansen <john.johansen@canonical.com>
|Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2011 22:02:39 -0700
|Subject: [PATCH 1/3] AppArmor: compatibility patch for v5 network controll
|
|Add compatibility for v5 network rules.
|
|Signed-off-by: John Johansen <john.johansen@canonical.com>
|---
| include/linux/lsm_audit.h | 4 +
| security/apparmor/Makefile | 19 +++-
| security/apparmor/include/net.h | 40 +++++++++
| security/apparmor/include/policy.h | 3 +
| security/apparmor/lsm.c | 112 ++++++++++++++++++++++++
| security/apparmor/net.c | 170 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| security/apparmor/policy.c | 1 +
| security/apparmor/policy_unpack.c | 48 +++++++++-
| 8 files changed, 394 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
| create mode 100644 security/apparmor/include/net.h
| create mode 100644 security/apparmor/net.c
|
|diff --git a/include/linux/lsm_audit.h b/include/linux/lsm_audit.h
|index 88e78de..c63979a 100644
|--- a/include/linux/lsm_audit.h
|+++ b/include/linux/lsm_audit.h
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

But it then asks me "File to patch: ".

How do I go about this?

**EDIT**: The reason I am doing that is that when I try to use `aa-enforce`, I get the following message:

`Setting /bin/ping to enforce mode.
Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?
Use --subdomainfs to override.`

and when i try to start Apparmor, i get this:

`Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/bin.ping (/etc/apparmor.d/bin.ping line 28): profile /bin/ping network rules not enforced`

Comment: Uh, the Ubuntu kernels already support AppArmor. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, my hosting company uses an in-house Ubuntu 12.04 and it seems to be problematic for apparmor. I edited my post with more details. Thanks

Comment: Is it a physical or virtual machine? Does it happen to be an [OpenVZ container](http://serverfault.com/questions/319953/apparmor-not-working-ubuntu-11-04-insize-openvz)?

Comment: Hi, I have a virtual machine but it's using Xen technology. Would that cause the same conflict as the OpenVZ incompatibility with Apparmor?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First which 3.2 kernel source are you using?

- An upstream kernel?
- An Ubuntu kernel that has apparmor already patched?

The Ubuntu 12.04 (3.2) kernel should already have the apparmor patches applied, so patching is not necessary. However if you need to patch, you should be in the root of the kernel source directory, not the patch directory.

This error

> Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted? Use --subdomainfs to override.

tells me that either the apparmor kernel module is not built in, enabled, or securityfs is not mounted.

Does the directory `/sys/module/apparmor` exist?

- If it exists, apparmor has been builtin but may not be enabled what is the value of
  `sudo cat /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/`?
- If `Y`, then apparmor was enabled at kernel load but the needed filesystems may not be mounted? Is securityfs mount? What is returned by the `mount` command?

  - You will be looking for a line like: `none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)`
  - If securityfs is mounted and apparmor is enabled what is the output of
    `ls -a /sys/kernel/security/apparmor`?

If the `/sys/module/apparmor` directory does not exist your kernel was not built with apparmor enabled. You will need to either install or build the kernel with apparmor builtin. It does not have to be enabled as the default LSM if you do not want, in such a situation providing `security=apparmor` as a kernel boot parameter will enable apparmor.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. `/sys/module/apparmor` doesn't exist on my system. The kernel I have seems to be the one at fault. It's an in-house kernel from my hosting company. They have contacted me saying that the problem was on their end and that they are fixing it. Thanks again. Regards